# The derivative of a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ in $SO(3)$

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ and  $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow SO(3)$ defined by $$\psi(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{3} R_x(x_i)R_z(y_i)$$
where $R_x,R_z$ are the rotation matrices around $x$-axis and the $z$-axis,respictively.

The Taylor–Young formula is given by :
$$ \psi(x+h)=\psi(x)+d_x\psi(h)+o(h)
$$
My questions are:

> Is it possible to apply the Taylor-Young formula?
> If the answer is affirmative, how then can I compute $d_x\psi(h)$?

Comment: If I understand well your notations, why don't you  begin by the factorization $\psi(x)=\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{3} R_z(y_i)}_{fixed !}\prod_{i=1}^{3} R_x(x_i)$ (where the $x_i$ are rotation angles, isn't it ?)

Comment: I am afraid that's not possible because $R_x$ and $R_z$ do not commute, i.e,  $R_x(x_i)R_z(y_i)\neq R_z(y_i)R_x(x_i)$.